# C# How do you query a subset of a Dictionary's entries based on the Value's type using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, types

In C# using Linq, is it possible to extract a subset of a Dictionary's entries based on the type of the Value, and cast it as a Dictionary with that type as value?

Basically, if you have a Dictionary like this one:

```
Dictionary<string, Object> Data;
```

Can you then do something like:

```
Dictionary<string, int> IntData = Data.Query();
```

Such that the new Dictionary gets all the entires whose Value is of Type int. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, int> IntData = Data.Where(k => k.Value is int)
   .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => (int) kv.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> IntData = Data
.Where(q => q.Value.GetType() == typeof(int))
.ToDictionary(q => q.Key, q => (int)q.Value);
```

Comment: What about null values in the dictionary?